# How to understand the relationship of the fundamental subspaces in these big pictures?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

I am struggling like 6 hours to understand what this content in the middle mean. Can u get me some clue to interpret it?

I understand all the stuff on the sides. So, **row space** is perp. to **null space** and they complement each other in R^m *(by complement I mean that linear combination of bases both spaces span R^m)* and the same for **column space** and **left null space** but in R^n.

But this stuff in the middle... I have no idea. I reread theory several times but didn't find a thing.

*P.s. These pictures from "Introduction to Linear Algebra ed.5, Gilbert Strang".*

[image: The first]

[image: The second]

Comment: Let me suggest you look over our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: In particular, look at our guidelines for [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) from which I take this quote: *Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title. The key parts of your question should not be in an embedded image such as a photo/screenshot/etc., such images are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries.*

Comment: How to describe the thing which I don't know how to describe?

Comment: @LeeMosher This might be a controversial take, but I think it's reasonable to include in an image in a question **about that image**. Also, in case you weren't aware, users without sufficient reputation are not allowed to embed images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middle stuff in the top image is saying where $Ax$ lies if $x$ is a nonzero element of the row space (it goes to a nonzero element of the column space) or if $x$ is in the null space (it goes to the zero vector).

The middle stuff in the bottom image is showing what's in the top image, as well as what happens when $x$ is not in either the row space or null space (the generic situation). In this case one can write it as $x=x_r+x_n$ where $x_r$ is in the row space and $x_n$ is in the null space, and $Ax$ will be $A(x_r+x_n)=Ax_r+Ax_n=Ax_r$.